# Search for a date that has this number python

Tags: python, django, datetime, search, django-orm

I am working on a search box type of functionality in searching for an available date in a model from a DateField date in Django.

Here are some sample dates, input, and desired output:

Sample dates:

```
05/01/2022
06/04/2021
01/02/2023
08/01/2022
07/31/2025
03/05/2022
01/28/2021
```

Sample Input-Output:

```
Input: 3   Output: 01/02/2023, 07/31/2025,  03/05/2022
Input: 31  Output: 07/31/2025
Input: 8   Output: 08/01/2022, 01/28/2021
Input: 6   Output: 06/04/2021
```

I hope the examples make it clear on what I have in mind. The purpose of this is to eliminate the use of a date picker and use a textbox instead. So if a user types in '3', all dates that have '3' in them will be the output and so on.

This is strictly searching by numbers only, so it is clear that the user won't input any strings.
Which means no 'February', 'Monday', and etc. inputs or outputs.

Is this kind of functionality possible or should I scrap this and turn to a date picker and search in a date range instead?

Currently, I'm thinking of the following ways to do this:

1. Generate a minimum and a maximum date object (based from the table) that has the number input then do a range filter.
2. Get all unique dates, convert them to strings, load them in a dataframe or list, then do the search from there.

Any insights or suggestions for the implementation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a regex function in your view.

Comment: Is it possible to use a regex for a DateField?